# Getting hue correct in a complex argument plot

Tags: plotting, complex, color, arguments

I'm trying to generate a picture of the phase of a complex function defined on a rectangle. I'm using Hue (which is cyclic) and DensityPlot, but it's leaving out certain "corners" of the plot, perhaps because the argument is (near to?) wrapping round there.

```
DensityPlot[Arg[f[s, t]]/(2*Pi), {s, 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

produces:

[image]

How can I fix this? The function is:

```
f[s_,t_]= 
Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(3 s)/10] Cos[(2 t)/
   5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 
    1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] + 
 Cos[\[Pi]/
   16] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 
    1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[(3 s)/10] Sin[(2 t)/5] - 
 Cos[(3 s)/10] Cos[(3 t)/
   5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[\[Pi]/
   16] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] + 
 Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[\[Pi]/16] Sin[(3 s)/
   10] Sin[(3 t)/5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] + 
 Cos[(7 s)/10] Cos[(2 t)/
   5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/
   16] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] - 
 Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/16] Sin[(7 s)/
   10] Sin[(2 t)/5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] + 
 Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(7 s)/10] Cos[(3 t)/
   5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 
    1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] + 
 Cos[\[Pi]/16] Sin[(7 s)/10] Sin[(3 t)/
   5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 
    1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] + 
 I (Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(2 t)/
      5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 
       1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[(3 s)/10] - 
    Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(3 s)/
      10] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 
       1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[(2 t)/5] - 
    Cos[(3 t)/5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[\[Pi]/
      16] Sin[(3 s)/10] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] - 
    Cos[(3 s)/10] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] Sin[\[Pi]/
      16] Sin[(3 t)/5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] - 
    Cos[(2 t)/5] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/
      16] Sin[(7 s)/10] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] - 
    Cos[(7 s)/10] Cos[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/
      16] Sin[(2 t)/5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] - 
    Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(3 t)/5] Sin[(7 s)/
      10] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 
       1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]] + 
    Cos[\[Pi]/16] Cos[(7 s)/10] Sin[(3 t)/
      5] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 1/2 ArcTan[1/(2 Sqrt[6])]] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - 
       1/2 ArcTan[2/Sqrt[21]]])
```

Comment: Can you give a rough estimate of your `f[s, t]` function? Or an example function that replicates this unexpected behavior? Thanks!

Comment: I have added the function now to my question. It might seem tricky but it's not; if you Plot3D the value of its argument you will see it has a very simple behaviour.

Comment: Add `PlotRange -> All`?

Comment: You may also want `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, I'm guessing, since you divide `Arg[]` by `2 Pi`.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, much appreciated. Indeed it is a duplicate, I didn't manage to find that question before.